# Java, variable comparison with array data

Tags: java, arrays, comparison-operators

I have an if statement that i would like to simplify 
 
`if ((s.getId() != 970) && (s.getId() != 357) && (s.getId() != 1323) && (s.getId() != 327) && (s.getId() != 1325) && (s.getId() != 1326) && (s.getId() != 1327) && (s.getId() != 1533) && (s.getId() != 1411) && (s.getId() != 482) && (s.getId() != 1532))
{
};`
You can see that it is repeating itself.
I would love to have it like this:

```
arrayType[] arrayName={970, 357, 1323, 327, 1325, 1326, etc };
if (!(s.getId().equals(arrayName[]))
{
};
```

Sorry for my bad syntax

EDIT: After reading Urahara's answer i came up with this:

```
int[] skillList = {970, 357, 1323, 327, 1325, 1326, 1327, 1533, 1411, 482, 1532};
            if (!Arrays.asList(skillList).contains(s.getId()))
            {

            }
```

Sorry for wrong tag

Comment: Is this a Java question or a JavaScript question? Mis-tagging your questions **wastes people's time.**

Comment: JavaScript has nothing to do with Java. Please tag your questions properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `ArrayList.Contains` function.

```
var arrayName = [970, 357, 1323, 327, 1325, 1326];

if ( !Arrays.asList(arrayName).contains(getId()) ){
         // the ID was not in the array
};
```